# Call to undefined relationship [] on model [App\Models\Area]

Tags: php, laravel

When calling following action:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Karellens\LAF\Http\Controllers\ApiController;
use Karellens\LAF\Facades\QueryMap;

class AreasController extends ApiController
{
    public function with_popular_descendants(Request $request)
    {
        $relations = QueryMap::explodeFields(request()->input('fields'));
        $relations['lower'] = function ($q) {
            $q->where('popular', 1);
        };

        return \App\Models\Area
            ::with($relations)
            ->where('area_type', 0)
            ->paginate($request->input('pagesize', 100))
            ->toArray()
            ;
    }
}
```

I get error: **Call to undefined relationship [] on model [App\Models\Area]**

On local server i dont have this error, only on production. I checked DB, yes have table area. I call artisan tinker and select all areas manually.

$relations return following code:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["lower"]=>
  object(Closure)#355 (2) {
    ["this"]=>
    object(App\Http\Controllers\AreasController)#305 (5) {
      ["version":protected]=>
      string(0) ""
      ["alias":protected]=>
      string(4) "area"
      ["modelClass":protected]=>
      string(16) "\App\Models\Area"
      ["middleware":protected]=>
      array(0) {
      }
      ["validatesRequestErrorBag":protected]=>
      NULL
    }
    ["parameter"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["$q"]=>
      string(10) "<required>"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you add `Area` model in you `controller`? You should `use Area` in your `AreasController`.`Area` model location should be right location.

Comment: The problem is this part `::with($relations)`. Can you dump the `$relations` and make sure that each value is actually a relationship in Area model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How me dump the $relations and make sure that each value is actually a relationship in Area?

Comment: i edit question, can you please answer

Comment: use var_dump() and then look at the pattern

Comment: @StefanHansch I believe the problem is the first item in your $relations which appears to be an empty string (?). The model will look for relationship "" (empty string) which doesn't exist and you get the error. You need to make sure the `QueryMap::explodeFields($input)` returns an array of relationship names **and nothing else**.